# How to replace all with macro ?

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I would like to replace all commas to points in my worksheet. The worksheet's name is world.

I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Just record a macro and get the code from there.

Comment: Every time you ask something in SO forums, you should at least include your tries and how far did you get with them. It's more probable other users will help you if they see some effort from your side.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it with macro, use following code:

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("world").Cells.Replace ",", "."
End Sub
```

or alternatively, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in your sheet and "Find and Replace" form will open

Comment: would you like to change `,` to `.` in values or in formulas?

Comment: There is a statement in my worksheet which is <Seri Pozisyon="C" Enstruman="A" ParaBirimi="TO1" DovizCinsi="A" Sektor="A" Ulke="5J" Deger="19315138,7344855"/> I want to change 19315138,7344855 to 19315138.7344855